# redirect from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, redirect

In asp.net 3.5 using vb i would like to go to another page in my application when the user clicks a button. what is the command for doing this?

Thank  you

Comment: just in case...view my answer posting. This is better if you want to hide variables in the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect("url")
```

Answer (score 1):

As TheTXI mentioned, `Response.Redirect` will work just fine.

However, your button click code won't run until late in the page life cycle.  Your server may have to do quite a bit of extra or unnecessary work first.  If this is the *only* thing you are doing, just wrap the button in an anchor tag:

```
<a href="url"><asp:button .../></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Response/RedirectpagetoanotherURLvbnet.htm) of how that would happen

```
 Public Sub Click (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
     Response.Redirect(SelectedItem.Text)
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

server.Transfer("url",true) is much better to use because it hides the variables you want to pass if there are any.